# Zend db Mysql sorting by count

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm looking for the right syntax using Zend db to show a table that is sorted by the count. For example, my mysql table looks like this:

```
Users         Description
1                topic1
1                topic2
2                topic3
```

I want the output to look like:

```
User 1 (2 descriptions)
User 2 (1 description)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw query you're looking for

```sql
SELECT users, COUNT(*) count
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY users
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Output:

```
| USERS | COUNT |
|-------|-------|
|     1 |     2 |
|     2 |     1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a4d3/1)** demo

I'm not an expert in Zend but your query may look something between the lines of

```php
$select = $db->select()
             ->from('table1', array('users', 'count' => '(COUNT(*))'))
             ->group('users')
             ->order('(COUNT(*)) DESC');
$stmt = $db->query($select);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```